# Comparing a char to the char '\"'

Tags: c, string, char

I'm working on C and need to recieve a string from the user in the format of "abcd", and to diagnose it to retrieve it as a string of "abcd"(int the code).
For some reason when I try to check if the first char in the string (that I've read using sscanf) is `"` it doesn't return it is, as you can see in the picture below. The watch says that data[0] is '"', but that data[0] == '"' is false, which is absurd.

[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: What code are we dealing with here? All I see is a screenshot of an ASCII 34 character.

Comment: @DYZ The format could include quotes, like JSON, but we don't know as we can't see the code.

Comment: This is not code, this is the Watch on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character in `data[0]` is probably a special quotation mark with the ASCII (or rather [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) code 147/0x93. It is a number in which the highest bit is 1, and as such is outside the 7 bit ASCII range. While the 7 bit ASCII codes are interpreted identically  across many character sets this is not so for 8 bit values (> 127). The "glyph" a given terminal or printer will show for 8 bit values depends on the char set is assumes (in your case, as mentioned, Windows-1252).

Last not least, because on your system chars are signed the debugger interprets the highest bit as a minus sign and shows a negative value. I think you can cast it in the debugger watch expression to unsigned char to obtain the positive equivalent.

That character cannot be entered directly with the keyboard; on Windows you can try to use the [Alt+Number block](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0) trick. When you enter the normal quotation mark you create a char with the ASCII code 34/0x22, which the compiler and debugger correctly claim is not identical.